# Make one or many post req at once - Node async issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my first attempt to make a proper application. However I have run into an problem which I for the life of me cannot find out how to solve.
The code bellow show my code for the function I have problem with.

The code is for register damages to an asset checking checkboxes for the damage type to register. Usually more than one is checked. (To register one damage work fine). The way I have tried to solve it is to store checked damages into an array and then loop over that array making a post request for each element in the array.

The queries that are being returned in the terminal is correct, however in the postgres log file I can see that is not the case. If I submit 5 different damages, 5 damages is being commited but the some damages are registered multiple times and others not at all.

I have got completely stuck with this issue. Is it a bad idea looping over each element and make a post request for each? Or how else should I solve it? If I use breakpoint in the browser and step through the code all damages are registered correct so there might be an async issue I have not spotted here?

```
  // submit form with selected damages
  $('#registerDamagesForm').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let = selectedDamage = $("input:checkbox[name=damage_type]:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  // loop over the array and call postDamage
  // for each element in array
  selectedDamage.forEach(function (selectedDamage) {
    let sendObject = {};
    sendObject["damage_type"] = selectedDamage;
    sendObject["poi_id"] = current_id;
    console.log("send " + Object.values(sendObject));
    postDamage(sendObject);
  })
});

// post request using promises 
function postDamage(damage) {
  console.log("post " + Object.values(damage));
  $.post({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/pois/skade',
    data: damage
  })
  .done(function (skade) {
    // do stuff with the returned damages
  })
};

// routes
router.post('/damage', (req, res) => {
  queries.createDamage(req.body)
  .then(damage => {
    res.json(damage);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error('get comment error ' + err);
  });
});

// make sql
createDamage(damage) {
    const sql = db.insert(damage).returning('*').into('damages');
    console.log(sql.toString());
    return sql;
  },
```

Comment: `let = selectDamage`? There are other oddities in this like the URI in the client doesn't match the route. To answer your question, 1 request will generally be better than multiple, in this case seems like it would make sense to send one request with all the damage types in the request body.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for you answer. The URI oddity is that I translated some of the variables into English and so maybe I missed on or two =) The let = selectedDamage is just the placeholder of the damages selected. I know it might be better to send one request instead of looping and do a few. I will try and make all the requests at the same time. But regardless of that I cannot see what would cause the problem atm.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with postgres but assuming the client requests are going up ok then the problem most likely lies with the server (possibly even the DB)

Comment: Can you please post your console log results? One thing that came up first that you can try impodentent request with PUT not POST, but thete also might be some problem with data duplication thats why I would like to take a look at console output